# Scroll percentage is not working but code is good

Tags: jquery

I want to get max percentage of scroll in main window. I tried to use that code but I get only strange numbers like 5223, 23000, 800:

```
var scrollmax=0;
$('window').scroll(function() {
    var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
    //if(scrollPercent>scrollmax)
    scrollmax=scrollPercent;
});
```

Is anything bad here? It is working in that example: http://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/2/

Comment: For one thing, I don't see you using scrollHeight... but from your example in the jsfiddle I don't see a problem with the bar because it matches the width percentage.  Also, where is height coming from? Is it the window height?

Comment: Very sorry I pasted bad code, I changed it please check it now :)

Comment: No worries... your jsfiddle seems to work.  I don't see the weird numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/rt271ued/1/

Comment: It's ok for me too.

Comment: It is good to me too but... when we look at database we can see this:
http://www60.zippyshare.com/v/1wcPGIS2/file.html
When I add alert to see value it is still number like that. You can see how it is working at live demo www.amalamastering.com :) Can you help me or propose other method to solve that problem? I want to get maximum percent of scroll user do on my website.